# Create a server with Python

Tags: html, python-3.x

I am working in a website project, and I am want make test in my cellphone for the responsive, but I don´t want unpload my project to a server, so, I saw that I can create a server with my computer and my local wifi, so I saw that I would create a file and import any things, but I don´t remember the things that I would do.

I want the file/script that can do this, and the explications for any modules.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some guides on making a node.js along with a python webserver

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VShtPwEkDD0 - node.js

https://pythonbasics.org/webserver/ <- py

This should answer everything you need

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a python script for a simple web server:

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8000

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print(f"Serving at http://localhost:{PORT}")
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

A oneliner directly from terminal, if someone wants

```bash
python3 -m http.server 8000
```

run it in the same directory as your `index.html`/`home.html`/ your root files exists

Then you should be able to open `http://IP_OF_YOUR_PC_ON_LOCAL_NETWORK:8000` on your mobile's browser